# Can't connect to SQL Server 2005 instance on remote server - Error 14

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to set up a DSN using ODBC on my local machine to a remote SQL Server 2005 instance.  I'm using SQL Server Authentication, but when I try to connect, I get SQL Server Error 14 - DBNETLIB Invalid Connection, SQL State: '01000' and '08001'.  The confusing thing is that I can connect just fine through SQL Server Management Studio on my local PC, I just can't setup a connection using ODBC.  Any help or insight is appreciated.  I've checked the usual suspects, Named Pipes and TCP/IP are both enabled on the server and port 1433 is open on both the local and remote machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, was able to get it going thanks to the suggestions on [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/82007/how-do-i-get-this-sql-server-odbc-connection-working) post

Looks, like I have to use the SQL Native Client driver instead of the SQL Server driver.  Wonder why is that's the case?  What's the difference??